# How do I create custom form using Stripe

Tags: javascript, php, html, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I'm trying to integrate stripe in my website but i'm having issues and don't know where to start. I have installed the library with composer but now I just do not know what to do as I want to create a payment form which will have two fields one for the customers name and the other for their email address as well as the other fields for credit card number etc.

Anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: There is no example files or readme/installation file?

Comment: The whole process is completely documented in stripe developer docs. Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do this using stripe js

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#including-stripejs

you just have to do is pass the proper Id to the input fields so stripe js will get all those details on form submit